# Undo change in ActiveSheet If range in another worksheet becomes less than cell below

Tags: excel

In `("Menu")` range `E15:E25` I'm entering values that are reflected in worksheet `("Pack Plan")` range `B5:P5` with some calculations, then in `("Pack Plan")` Range `B6:P6` I have other calculated values. I need a code that will undo any change in `("Menu")` range `E15:E25` and MsgBox "Adjust Pack Plan" If that change caused the value of any cell in `("Pack Plan")` range `B5:P5` to be less than the value of cell in same column 1 row below, (offset(-1,0)). Currently I have 15 IF's to execute this. I need a single IF argument which will allow for more conditions to be added without having to duplicate them for each IF.
`("Menu")` is the active sheet.

Answers to similar questions didn't work for me.
Thank you.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        If (Target.Column = 5) Then

'I'm trying to consolidate the following IF arguments into 2 set's of IF code instead of having IF's for each cell in range.
'First these two If's:

            If Worksheets("Crème").Range("C11").Value > Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("B5").Value Then
                MsgBox "Missing Ingredient!"
                Application.Undo
            End If
            If Worksheets("Crème").Range("C12").Value > Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("I5").Value Then
                MsgBox "Missing Ingredient!"
                Application.Undo
            End If
            
'Then the following 15 IF's:

            If Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("B5").Value < Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("B6").Value Then
                MsgBox "Adjust Packout Plan"
                Application.Undo
            End If
            If Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("C5").Value < Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("C6").Value Then
                MsgBox "Adjust Packout Plan"
                Application.Undo
            End If
            If Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("D5").Value < Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("D6").Value Then
                MsgBox "Adjust Packout Plan"
                Application.Undo
            End If
            If Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("E5").Value < Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("E6").Value Then
                MsgBox "Adjust Packout Plan"
                Application.Undo
            End If
            If Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("F5").Value < Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("F6").Value Then
                MsgBox "Adjust Packout Plan"
                Application.Undo
            End If
            If Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("G5").Value < Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("G6").Value Then
                MsgBox "Adjust Packout Plan"
                Application.Undo
            End If
            If Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("H5").Value < Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("H6").Value Then
                MsgBox "Adjust Packout Plan"
                Application.Undo
            End If
            If Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("I5").Value < Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("I6").Value Then
                MsgBox "Adjust Packout Plan"
                Application.Undo
            End If
            If Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("J5").Value < Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("J6").Value Then
                MsgBox "Adjust Packout Plan"
                Application.Undo
            End If
            If Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("K5").Value < Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("K6").Value Then
                MsgBox "Adjust Packout Plan"
                Application.Undo
            End If
            If Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("L5").Value < Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("L6").Value Then
                MsgBox "Adjust Packout Plan"
                Application.Undo
            End If
            If Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("M5").Value < Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("M6").Value Then
                MsgBox "Adjust Packout Plan"
                Application.Undo
            End If
            If Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("N5").Value < Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("N6").Value Then
                MsgBox "Adjust Packout Plan"
                Application.Undo
            End If
            If Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("O5").Value < Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("O6").Value Then
                MsgBox "Adjust Packout Plan"
                Application.Undo
            End If
            If Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("P5").Value < Worksheets("Pack Plan").Range("P6").Value Then
                MsgBox "Adjust Packout Plan"
                Application.Undo
            End If
        End If
        
' code to be consolidated ends here

        If (Target.Column = 3) Then
            If (Target.Offset(0, 2)) <> "" Then
                Application.Undo
                MsgBox "Clear Batch Size First", vbExclamation, "RESTRICTED"
            End If
        End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your new and improved description of the problem I have revised my suggested solution. Please try the code below. It should run in response to the Change event on your "Menue" tab.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim WsPack  As Worksheet
    Dim C       As Long                 ' loop counter: Column
    
    Select Case Target.Column
        Case 5
            Set WsPack = Worksheets("Pack Plan")
            With Worksheets("Crème")
                If .Cells(11, "C").Value > WsPack.Range("B5").Value Or _
                   .Cells(12, "C").Value > WsPack.Range("I5").Value Then
                    AppUndo 2
                    Exit Sub            ' I added this
                End If
                For C = 2 To 16
                    If .Cells(5, C).Value > WsPack.Cells(6, C).Value Then
                        AppUndo 3
                        Exit Sub        ' I added this
                    End If
                Next C
            End With
        Case 3
            If (Target.Offset(0, 2)) <> "" Then AppUndo 1
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub AppUndo(Idx As Integer)
                    
    Dim Msg(1 To 3) As Variant              ' Message Texts, title, style
    
    Msg(1) = Array("Clear batch size first", "RESTRICTED", vbExclamation)
    Msg(2) = Array("Missing ingredient", "INCOMPLETE PREPARATION", vbCritical)
    Msg(3) = Array("Adjust packout plan", "EXCESS CONTENT", vbExclamation)
    
    MsgBox Msg(Idx)(0), Msg(Idx)(2), Msg(Idx)(1)
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .Undo
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

As you see, I didn't really reduce the number of tests but I improved the efficiency of the syntax by employing (a) a loop and (b) a sub-routine both of which serve to reduce and avoid repetitive code.

**Explainer (26 Aug 2020)**

Please note the rationale behind this part of the code.

```
    Set WsPack = Worksheets("Pack Plan")
    With Worksheets("Crème")
        If .Cells(11, "C").Value > WsPack.Range("B5").Value Or _
           .Cells(12, "C").Value > WsPack.Range("I5").Value Then
```

There are two worksheets to be referenced. One of them is declared in the `With` statement, the other as a variable. Neither of them is (necessarily) the ActiveSheet. Instead, the cells in Worksheets("Crème") are linked to the `With` statement by leading periods, which are essential for ***not*** referencing the ActiveSheet but the named one. Cells in the other sheet must be identified giving the full name of the variable. Therefore it's advantageous to choose a short name. "Worksheets("Pack Plan")" would also work but it isn't short.

Which sheet is declared by variable and which one by the `With` statement is determined by how many times each sheet is referenced. Obviously, the `With` statement makes for shorter code. That's why that's the way to apply to the majority of the references. When I wrote the code I thought that both are referenced equally often and I chose the first sheet in the lines to be linked to the `With` statement for better legibility. But now you say that I was mistaken in identifying the sheets to be referenced and there is a large majority of references to `WsPack`. Therefore you may prefer to invert the use of variable and `With` statement to adapt to the revised usage.

Comment: Hi Variatus, thanks for your quick reply, I forgot to mention that Sheet1 is the active sheet. is there a way to code this other than entering each cell location. I have a code that works but doesn't sound right, See my edited question with the code currently in use.

Comment: My code responds to all cells in B5:P5. You should test it thoroughly before you comment.

Comment: Your code is indeed responding to the entire range (B5:P5). But is not working because the range is in another sheet, not on the active sheet. Sheet1 ("Menu") is the ActiveSheet, where the change event takes place. Sheet2 ("Pack Plan") is where the "IF" condition takes place.

Comment: Wow, you really overextended yourself, its much appreciated. Its working fine now, there was one flaw. The AppUndo Msg(3) was triggered with any change in ("Menu") E10:E23 regardless of whether Cells(5, C).Value [code line 16] was greater or less then Cells(6, C).Value, I also noticed that the argument was '>' instead of '<' So i modified line 16 to "If .WsPack.Cells(5, C).Value < WsPack.Cells(6, C).Value Then". Without the added WsPack preceding .Cells(5, C) i was getting a run time error "13". just checking with you if this modification is the way to go or there is another way to do it.

Comment: Sorry Variatus, I cant upvote your answer because I don't have 15 reputations...

Comment: The runtime error you got is likely due to the spelling of the "Creme" and a worksheet by the name specified in the `With` statement isn't found. Please also read the "Explainer" I have added to the above solution.

Comment: Understood.
How can i add a `If vbOK Then` go to sheet "Pack Plan" cell A1 to 
Msg(3) = Array("Adjust packout plan", "EXCESS CONTENT", vbExclamation)

Comment: Understood.
How can I add a `If vbOK Then` go to sheet "Pack Plan" cell A1 to: 
Msg(3) = Array("Adjust packout plan", "EXCESS CONTENT", vbExclamation)
I added `vbOKCancel` to the line above and then `IF vbOK Then` `Sheets ("Pack Plan").Range(A1).Select` but cant get it to work.
Thank you.

Comment: You're on the worksheet on whose Change event your code is acting. To use that sheet's code module to select a cell on another worksheet means courting trouble because you have to activate that sheet before you can select anything on it, and the Change event won't like its host being deactivated before it has run its course.

Comment: `Dim Answer As VbMsgBoxResult: Answer = MsgBox("Text", vbOKCancel, "Title")` will give you a variable you can use in an IF statement. The buttons of the MsgBox are decided by the argument. You might use vbYesNo or even vbYesNoCancel. Be sure to allow for user to press the X. You might change sub AppUndo to a function, call MsgBox differently depending upon Idx and return the result if there is one.